# Is John Wick ex-military?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, john-wick

John Wick has a *Fortis Fortuna Adiuvat* tattoo on his back and in the nightclub scene he is seen wearing his watch inside like military personnel.

Coincidence? Or is he ex military?

An ideal answer would be one quoting the director or other cast and crew if they ever said something about it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Source**: http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/John_Wick

> John Wick, prior to being a hitman, served in the United States Marine
>   Corps. This can be noticed by the tattoo on his back, which from Latin
>   to English says "Fortune Favors the Brave", the motto of the United
>   States Marine Corps, 2nd battalion, 3rd Marines who have been through
>   5 tours of duty.

**Update**: Also from the wiki,

> According to Wick's Crimefest description, he and Chains were former
>   comrades during their time in the military.

It is an established fact in the Payday games that John Wick served in the military.

[Payday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payday:_The_Heist) is widely believed to be canon which is evident from many facts including the following

- John Wick literally being in the game
- "Continental Coins" being used as a form of in game currency used to upgrade the safehouse.
- There exists a John Wick weapons purchaseable DLC pack for the game which features the same weapons from the movies.

The creative team has not made any statements regarding this but I suspect it is because the obscurity of John Wick's past is a major factor in the appeal of this movie. However, it is safe to assume that he did serve in the military prior to becoming a hitman.

Comment: It's not like American Marines invented the latin proverb that is older than US by two thousand years... seems pretty thin reasoning to me.

Comment: Maybe he was just a big fan of [Pliny the Elder](https://en.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Pliny_the_Elder#Quotes)

Comment: This doesn't really provide any information that wasn't in the question. His appearance in the game matches his appearance in the movies, but the quote from the wiki seems to be speculation based on the same appearance.

Comment: There is also going to be a John Wick "universe" spin off TV series The Continental (Starz) - maybe somethings will become clearer with this series, since Wick may return at some point and/or other characters could relate to his past? http://deadline.com/2018/01/john-wick-tv-series-adaptation-starz-lionsgate-keanu-reeves-1202241870/

Comment: @MiloP added another quote from the wiki.

Comment: @DarthLocke starring Keanu Reeves?

Comment: @Vishwa, No, but the Deadline article said they want him to "appear" in the series (so reoccurring or special guest star?) --so it should tie-into his story. My understanding is that series is to revolve around the Hotel...

Comment: Read the article, John Wick universe is mainly based on Wick. Keanu should be main impression for people who attracted so much attention to the series. without him, I'm not sure how it'll do on small screen. Limitless is a good example. I liked tv series, but it wasn't as good as Jason Morra in it..  Could be wrong.I'm just sayin

Comment: @Vishwa I agree about Limitless, but Bradley Cooper did appear on multiple occations with intentions of him being heavier in season 2 (his schedule was a bit of problem). Personally I wish CBS AA would of picked it up instead of the main CBS station--the genre stuff clearly does better there and where CBS will let it grow!

Comment: @DarthLocke thats what I said. even though Bradley Cooper did appear in sildelines, which Keanu Reeves will do in Continental, Limitless was a failure. Don't get me wrong, I kinda enjoyed the show, but Cooper was the main attraction and Keanu'll be for the continental. They hope Continental will be huge without Keanu, but History suggests otherwise, Sadly though.....

Comment: Although I was glad Cooper was in it, I loved the cast already being a fan of Jennifer Carpenter, Georgina Haig, Hill Harper, ect. & I think Jake McDorman was a great lead that could totally hold his own. I just think Limitless didn't need Cooper as much as Continental will need Reeves. I think Limitless could of expanded on the mythos without Cooper, but like a lot of Network tv series, suffered from being a hybrid serialization & SOTW and took a little too long to uncover something substantial, but I think CBS axed it, because their crime dramas are more succesful & became their brand...